# Simon Says challenge activity

Tags: python, loops, break, continue

I am brand new to coding and working my way through an intro class via Zybooks. This challenge activity is asking me to add one point to user_score for every letter that is a match and break the loop when there is a mismatch. Simon_pattern and user_pattern are both input. This is the code I have so far:

```
user_score = 0
simon_pattern = input()
user_pattern  = input()


for character in simon_pattern:
    for input in user_pattern:
        if input == character:
            user_score += 1
            continue
        
    if input != character:
        break
    
print('User score:', user_score)
```

The code works, but the returned value is wrong. Given simon_pattern ='RRGBRYYBGY'and user_pattern = 'RRGBBRYBGY' the output should be User Score: 4, but my User Score is coming out as 3.

I'm not quite sure what part of my code needs fixing and unfortunately zybooks does not give you any hints. Thanks in advance for the help of this awesome community!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi and welcome to coding! A few notes: Notice how the `input()` function is used to gather input from the user? Because of this, it is considered a keyword and it is bad practice to name your variables `input`, because it will overwrite the reference to the function.

Now considering your problem. Instead of a nested loop I would use a single `for` lop and check the characters at each index within both strings. If they match, add a point. Otherwise, break the loop. You also want to stop the loop if it goes beyond the number of characters in either pattern. One trick for that is to find the minimum length between both patterns. The `min` function is useful for this.

```py
user_score = 0
simon_pattern = input()
user_pattern  = input()


length = min(len(simon_pattern), len(user_pattern))

for i in range(length):
    if user_pattern[i] == simon_pattern[i]:
        user_score += 1
    else:
        break
        

print('User score:', user_score)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your feedback - I did realize I should not have used input in that context. In your opinion, is my code not counting correctly because I did not consider a length for the inputs? I'm finding it difficult to really grasp concepts when there is no feedback from the program.

Comment: Your code is not counting correctly because the nested for loops. Consider `for character in simon_pattern`. The first simon character will be `R` in your example. Now consider `for input in user_pattern`. The first user input will be `R`, the second would be `R`, and the third would be `G`. But you never executed the next iteration of your first loop, so you are still comparing the 3rd letter of the user input to the first letter of the simon input.

Comment: @SwanSong that's why I recommend a single for loop instead of a nested for loop. That way you compare the characters at the appropriate indices. The nested for loop that you wrote compares every character in the user_pattern to the first character of the simon_pattern. Then it compares every character in user_pattern to the next character of the simon_pattern and so on (until the `break` is hit). Your User Score was 3 because there are 3 `R`'s in user_pattern and the first character of simon_pattern is `R`.

Answer (score 0):

This should work :

```py
user_score = 0
simon_pattern = input()
user_pattern  = input()


for simon_character, user_character in zip(simon_pattern, user_pattern):
    if simon_character == user_character:
        user_score += 1
    else:
        break

print('User score:', user_score)
```

Be careful not to redefine the Python keywords such as `input` or `print` for example. The rest of your program could be modified if you need to reuse these functions

Answer (score -1):

It may no longer be relevant, but here is another way to solve that problem:

```
    user_score = 0
    simon_pattern = input()
    user_pattern  = input()

    for i in range(10):
        if simon_pattern[i] == user_pattern[I]:
            user_score += 1
            continue
        else:
            break

    print('User score:', user_score)
```

My issue was not remembering how to compare the two strings one letter at a time. So for anyone that happens to be taking a similar class, this is a solution that uses information that you have already learned. I'm not sure that it is the most efficient solution, but it works.

Comment: There are a lot of issues. First, you use `i in range(10)`. What if the patterns are more or less than 10 characters? In the first instance, the result can be wrong. In the second, an error will be thrown. Next, you are using `continue` inside your `if` statement. Since you have no other code after the `else` statement, this effectively does nothing. Lastly, you have a typo of `user_pattern[I]`. `I` is undefined in your code and, from context, should instead be `user_pattern[i]`. At this point, the result would be the same as @h0r53 answer, which additionally checks for different sized inputs.